# What phrase can describe the final moments before a deadline?

Tags: american-english, british-english, sentence, time

I got a call from a friend while 10 minutes were left of my birthday. I want to put it like that

> The phone call from him ___________ was the icing on the cake.

How to express that only 10 minutes were left of that day? should the time thing be in the blank space?
Is the following sentence correct?

> The phone call from him **10 minutes** prior to end of the day was the icing on the cake.

Comment: *The phone call from him at 23:50 (or 11:50 pm)...*

Comment: @DanBron: Dear diary, 2350 hours: he called. Oh dark thirty: I cut the cake :)

Answer (score 5):

Try:

> The phone call from him **[at the eleventh hour](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/the-eleventh-hour?q=eleventh%20hour)** was the icing on the cake.

Also, Kristina was magnanimous enough to let me use one from her post:

> The phone call from him **[in the nick of time](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/in-the-nick-of-time?q=nick%20of%20time)** was the icing on the cake.

(Oxford)

Comment: Eleventh-hour is spot on perfect.

Answer (score 3):

"The phone call from him [at the last minute](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/last%20minute?s=t) was the icing on the cake"

> **Last minute**
>
> *Noun* - The time just preceding a deadline or when some decisive action must be taken.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Although this phrase seems to be specifying the *last* minute before the deadline expires, it is actually understood to mean *just before* the deadline and does not need to be literally the last minute.

Comment: Also works as an adjective: "The last minute phone call was the icing on the cake."

Answer (score 3):

***"Just under the wire"*** means that something occurred just prior to the deadline (in the case of your birthday, midnight of the next day).

> "The phone call from him *just under the wire* was the icing on the cake."

***[under the wire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sports_idioms#U)***:

> Horse racing: At the very last moment; in the nick of time; barely within some accepted parameters or limits. "The report was handed in just under the wire." Or, "At five-foot-five, he was under the wire for the height requirement for enlistment." From the practice of stretching a wire over the finish line at a racetrack. AHDI dates to the first half of the 20th century;[79] OED dates the horse-racing term to 1889 and the figurative sense to 1929

```
from Wikipedia's List of sports idioms
```

Comment: +1. Another suggestion from your post:  `in the nick of time`. You might wanna add that.

Comment: Thanks @TusharRaj.  It's very similarly used but from a different origin so I would probably make that a different answer.  Go for it! :-)